# A project's three module rely on three different virtual environment

Tags: python, linux, flask, web, virtualenv

Now I have a project and I think it can be divided into three different modules like below.

```
project
│   README.md
│ 
└───flask_web
│   └───app_folder
│   |   └───  ...
|   |   └───  ...
|   |   |   __init__.py
|   |
│   │   app_run.py
│   └───venv
│       └──bin        
|   
│      
└───Fate
|   └─── ...
|   └───env
|       └───python36
|           └───venv
|               └───bin
|
└───fake_data_algorithm
    └─── ...
    └───venv
        └───bin
```

The first part 'web' is a flask application providing web service, it requires a virtual environment.

The second part 'fate' is a open source project for federal learning and also needs a virtual environment.If I want to start the system for federal learning process, I have to source 'fate/bin/init_env.sh' to activate the providing environment.

The third part 'fake_data_algorithm' is used to generate fake data based on the 'data' folder, which also requires virtual environment for some python packages.

Because the after the 'web' application getting the request from browser, it will call
'fate' or 'fake_data_algorithm', but both of them are in a different virtual environment, so I should source the environment again.

Something really puzzles me:Is there a mechanism that can enable the whole project keep running `without switching the virtual environment`.And because the "fate" is a relatively close part, I want to keep the virtual environment of 'fate' as far as possible(try to avoid put all the python packages in a single environment under project).

Comment: "ry to avoid put all the python packages in a single environment under project" -> I don't really understand the motivation for this.  A project should _run_ in a single virtual environment.  It may make sense to have separate venvs for _development_, but not for execution.

Comment: I wrote this question because the 'fate' folder is not written by myself, it is a federal learning frame from github and maintained by Tencent(an Internet enterprise).And it does provide a environment for the project, so I don't want to change it. Now I have a flask web application that want to call API of fate(important). I think when I run the flask web application, I need a virtual environment for flask web. So does for 'fake_data_algorithm' .And I don't know how to handle this awkward situation because it seems these three folder require virtual environment respectively

Comment: From your words it seems only when I'm developing this project that virtual environment is required, but when I run it as a service in Linux, the virtual environment is not required any more.I don't understand it. If venvs are no longer needed  for execution, where are the packages the projects need when executing.

Comment: Generally, projects will recommend creating a virtual environment because it prevents conflicts between the project and the system Python or other projects.  However as long as your three projects don't have any conflicting requirements, you can create a single virtualenv and install the requirements for all three projects and then use that virtualenv to run your project.

Comment: yes, and so the question is the three modules' packages may conflict.And I just want 'fate' work without any change(but it seems hard)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Something really puzzles me:Is there a mechanism that can enable the
> whole project keep running without switching the virtual
> environment.And because the "fate" is a relatively close part, I want
> to keep the virtual environment of 'fate' as far as possible(try to
> avoid put all the python packages in a single environment under
> project).

Switching virtual environment is just a comfort feature when you are inputting commands into your CLI. You do not have to switch virtual environments manually.

You can write a small batch script to execute your projects:

```
#!/bin/sh

cd /home/username/project/flask_web &&
./venv/bin/python ./app_run.py
```

This will set the working directory to `/home/username/project/flask_web` (important...) and use the working directory's virtual environment to execute your project.

Depending on your IDE you can also select in the project settings which Python Interpreter/Virtual Environment to use.
So in your IDE you can have multiple projects opened but they all use different Python Interpreters and libraries.

Comment: Thank you , but I still have some questions: so If I write a shell script to do this, the virtual environment is actually still switching. I wonder when the environment changes, will the flask application(web service) still work normally as before. (because  in this case when flask_web call API from 'fate' or 'fake_data_algorithm', the relying environment still should switch, either manually or automatically)

Comment: I wrote this under the assumption that's 3 independent projects that interface with each other through an API. You cannot switch Python interpreter during runtime. You cannot make a single Python project rely on Python modules that are on different versions.

Comment: well, now I realize this design mode won't work.And I find another way but I don't know is it correct: we do not run the whole procedure(web application->fate or web-application>algorithm) in a single project, but create three different python project(flask_web, fate,  fake_data_algorithm) and call API in the three project.

Comment: If those are 3 independent python project it works. The API can also be a CLI call and you read the output. But you cannot make a python project change its own Python interpreter and its libraries during execution.